# Determine whether a polyomino has a hole

Tags: area, polyomino

Suppose I know the $(x,y)$ coordinates of the corners of all the unit squares making up a connected polyomino. Is there a simple/elegant way to determine if the polyomino has a hole in it, merely by using these coordinates?

Polyomino with no holes:

[image: simply connected polyomino with no interior holes]

Polyomino with two holes:

[image: connected polyomino with two interior holes]

Note: I've already determined a solution by a process similar to the following list, **but I am wondering if there is a nicer/cleverer way**:

1. Find the smallest bounding rectangle (using $x_\text{min},\, x_\text{max},\, y_\text{min}\,$ and $\,y_\text{max}$).
2. Make a list of all blank squares on the perimeter of this rectangle.
3. For each blank square in this list, look up, down, left and right for more blank squares (that are inside the rectangle), adding all of these to the list.
4. Loop step 3 over this list until no new blank squares are found.
5. Sum the number of blank squares in this list with the known number of shaded squares. If this sum is less than the area of the bounding rectangle, we know there is a hole.

Is there a theorem/perspective I've overlooked that would have provided an elegant solution?

Comment: Does the yellow polynomial contain 1 or 2 holes?

Comment: Two. [I’ve edited the question to make that clearer.]

Comment: @NickC tag the user by adding `@` before their name so that they get notified that you have replied to them

Comment: Not an answer, but a comment: well-done specifying that the polyomino needs to be connected. Here are two distinct polyominos which give the same set of corners of unit squares. One of them has a hole. The other has no hole, but is not orthogonally connected. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dw6Pw.png

Answer (score 6):

Try [Pick's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem): if $B$ is the number of grid points on the boundary of the polyomino, $I$ is the number of grid points in the interior, and $A$ is the number of squares, then $$A+1-I-\frac B2=H$$ where $H$ is the number of holes.

To compute $B$ and $I$, iterate over each  vertex of each square. Keep a count of the number of times each point appears. If a point appears in one, two, or three of the squares, it is a boundary point. If it is on four squares, it is an interior point.

Comment: I also considered using Pick’s theorem, but I couldn’t  see an easy way to determine if an arbitrary point is on the boundary. If you think Pick’s could work here, do you have an idea for separating the boundary points from the interior points in the given point list?

Comment: @NickC You can travel along the boundary. For each boundary point P of your travel you can find out, which of the four possible squares, where P is a corner, exists. From this you can decide which is the next boundary point.

Comment: You know where the squares are.  Iterate over the vertices of the squares and keep a count of the number of times each point appears.  If a point appears in one, two, or three of the squares, it is a boundary point.  If it is on four squares, it is an interior point.

Comment: @miracle173 The boundary includes the holes.  If you could “travel along the boundary,” you wouldn't need to use Pick's theorem.

Comment: @MJD you are right, I only thought of the outer boundary.

Comment: @miracle163 Thanks for the edit

Answer (score 1):

You can travel along the outer boundary, the boundary to the unrestricted area. You can calculate the area enclosed by this outer boundary while you are travelling along the boundary (similar to a [planimeter](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=_W35iDhRfZg)): start with  $A=0$. Add $x$ to $A$ if you go from $(x,y)$ to $(x,y-1)$ and subtract it if you go from $(x,y)$ to $(x,y+1)$. If only $x$ changes but $y$ does not, $A$ does not change. At the end of the travel $A$ is equal to the area. If this area  is finally equal to the number of squares, then there are no holes. If it is larger, then there are holes.
To start choose the points with the lowest $x$-coordinate $x_0$ and from these choose the one with the lowest $y$ coordinate $y_0$. This is the left
lower vertex of a square. The first move is from this vertex $(x_0,y_0)$ up to $(x_0,y_0+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Pick's Theorem has unexpected results for some holey polyominoes. Take for example the smallest such, the holey heptomino. It is not a correct candidate for Pick's theorem, as the external boundary of the polyomino is not distinct from the boundary of the hole.
As a result,
H = A + 1 - I - B/2 evaluates as 7 + 1 - 0 - 15/2 = 1/2
There is a way to fix this, counting D = vertices surrounded only by 2 squares adjacent diagonally (note that such vertices get counted twice, in both B and D).
The new formula is H = A + 1 - I + (D - B)/2.